# How to use varnish in microservices architecture?

Tags: varnish, microservices, vert.x

We have different microservices which calls each other. Many calls in these are redundant so we are planning to use varnish as a cache layer so we can save the redundant calls.

I have following questions -

1) Is varnish suitable for such use case. If not is there any other tool ?

2) How can we configure Varnish for maximum throughput and minimum latency between different services. We have vert.x based services with async calls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Caching layer for different microservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44265295/caching-layer-for-different-microservices)

Comment: You already asked almost the same question a few hours back.